# Make a USB in Ubuntu to boot a Macbook Air

Tags: usb, macbook

The title pretty much covers it all, but I want to create a USB drive with Ubuntu on it to boot a Macbook Air. My computer has Ubuntu 14.04 on it, and that's it. How do I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by boot a Macbook Air?
If you mean a bootable usb to put an ISO in, use the 'Startup Disk Creator' program.

More info here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Comment: But I thought it only allowed a boot to a Windows based computer or one already running linux